# Meeting problems while using jQuery plugin in the modal of Angular-strap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-strap

I try to use the [mention.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js) in my project, but it doesn't work well in the modal of Angular-strap. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DW4xTU9nTegyV1s9Tq6O)

```
myApp.controller("CreateModalCtrl", function($scope) {
    $("#members").mention({users: usersInfo});
});
```

In the main page, the mention.js works well:
[image: works]

But when it comes to the modal page, the plugin doesn't work. 
[image: not work]

Besides, the plnker can not show the modal page, and you can copy the code from the plnker to your local project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myApp.controller("CreateModalCtrl", function($scope) {
//$("#members").mention({users: usersInfo}); 
setTimeout(function(){
      $("#members").mention({users: usersInfo});            
      $scope.$apply();}, 0);});
```

And then it works...